# How to convert a line type layer to a point type layer in qgis?

Tags: qgis, postgis, layers

I need to convert a linetype to a point layer in qgis, these layers are in .shp format.

Comment: Your question probably solves with 'Create points along lines' algorithm in Processing Toolbox. Be carefull with the CRS you're using. If your data stored in Geographic Coordinate System you better transform it into Projected one to use convenient units in 'Distance' option (metres of feet)

Comment: Can you add some more info about your aim? There are tools to extract the nodes of each line in nearly any software (you tagged qgis and postgis). Is this what you want? Or start/end?

Comment: Indeed, need to know if you want one point per line, or one point per vertex.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "convert geometry" tool of the **MMQGIS plug-in** : choose modify/convert geometry type.

In the geometry type list box choose "nodes" and the result is loaded in a new shapefile ...

**Quicker way** : QGIS geoalgorithms/Vector geometry tools/extract nodes (in the processing toolbox)